# Can a view be added to see how many times I've voted on Area51?

Tags: feature-request, area-51

I'd like to see how close I am to earning the "Civic Duty" badge on Area51. It would be nice to be able to see my total vote count for on- and off-topic questions in my profile (similar to the view I see on most every other Stack Exchange site).

Comment: +1, I've always wondered why that wasn't there.